# Delay new mail from showing up in my gmail inbox until a certain time of day?

Tags: gmail

Is there a way to delay all my new mail from showing up in Gmail until certain times of day? e.g. I only want new mail to show up at 10am and 4pm.

Can this be built with a chrome extension or something?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about a Chrome extension, but it can be done with a Google Script. If you're not willing to write your own script (or don't know how), you can find a few by googling "google script delay incoming mail" (without the quotes).

Either way, log into your Google account, go to http://www.google.com/script/start/ and click on the blue "Start Scripting" button. Then select "Blank project" and either copy/paste the script of your choice or start coding.

When you're done, you'll probably need to set some triggers for your script. Just use the "Resources" >> "Current Project's Triggers" >> "Add one now" menu. If you don't know what a trigger is, don't worry: all you'll have to do is provide the name of the script (which you'll know because you'll have just pasted/written it), select the "time-driven" option and then set the time.

If you do want to write your own script, you'll need to know some JavaScript. Also, make sure to tag any future questions with JavaScript so that the right people will find it and help you.

Hope this helps!